# Chinese Lunar calendar not available in sharepoint 2010

Tags: calendar, sharepoint-calendar

In our sharepoint farm, some of the users were trying to use Chinese Lunar Calendar, However, this calendar does not appear in the calendar types (Under regional settings). I tried installing Chinese Language pack, But still this calendar was not not available. Any sugesstions would be of great help !

Answer (score 0):

The Chinese Lunar Calendar only becomes available when the regional settings of the site itself is set to Chinese.  Simply changing the user language does not accomplish this.

Comment: Let me be more specific, What the user is trying to do is to use Alternate calendar under the regional settings. Just like many other calendar types are available (Like hebrew etc), he was looking for this calendar type so that he could get the dates according to Chinese calendar.

Comment: Ah, in that case, it's not an option.  Here is a list of the available alternate calendars: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint/microsoft.sharepoint.client.regionalsettings.alternatecalendartype.aspx

Comment: This page also lists the available types: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147944(v=office.14).aspx#Calendar.  Beyond this, SharePoint doesn't offer any out-of-the-box way to get an alternative calendar.